# iOS WKWebView.scrollView delegate cause BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, fixed

My viewController has a UIView property which contains a WKWebView. And I set the WKWebView scrollView delegate to my viewController, which is a public function of my UIView subClass and called in my viewController.

The issue is when I call `[viewController popViewControllerAnimated]`, it will crash on `[UIScrollView setDelegate:]`.
I have fixed the issue by add `viewController.UIView.WKWebView.scrollView.delegate = nil;` in viewController's **dealloc**.

But why? WKWebView's dealloc is after viewController's dealloc, I suppose viewController is set to nil and dealloc in WKWebView will update its delegate to nil then cause BAD_ACCESS? But why dealloc will inplicit call setDelegate???

Comment: Could your provide a bit more info? How you added your `scrollView ` to view? with strong reference or not?

Answer (score 3):

In similar situation for WKWebView I had similar issue on assigning delegate to self. Implementing deinit resolved for me:

```
deinit {
    webView.scrollView.delegate = nil
}
```

Comment: saved my day :-) It was working on iOS > 9 and was crashing on iOS 9. Turns out, that Apple must have fixed it in iOS 10, so that the delegate is now stored weak, instead of string before :-)

Answer (score 1):

For ObjC, setting the scrollView delegate to nil in `dealloc` was still causing a crash.
Had to nil the delegate in `didMoveToSuperview`

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    if (self.superview == nil) {
        self.scrollView.delegate = nil;
    }
}
```

These threads helped me

https://github.com/readium/r2-navigator-swift/pull/4

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=159980