# iOS WKWebView Crash on ios 8 and ios 9 When navigationController pop

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios9, wkwebview

I have a custom `wkwebView` called `SSWkWebView`.
And I have two viewControllers (A & B) . [self.view addsubview: SSWkWebView]
When I pop B VC to A VC , crash happened.
And crash only happens on ios 8 and ios 9, but not with ios 10.

> Log info: objc[31702]: Cannot form weak reference to instance
>   (0x7ffe21182c00) of class NSKVONotifying_SSWKWebView. It is possible
>   that this object was over-released, or is in the process of
>   deallocation.

I have done some research, here is the link :
*[Login flow failing after upgrading to iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842995/login-flow-failing-after-upgrading-to-ios9)*
which seems not working. Then I tried another approach that adding the following code:

```
- (void)dealloc {
wkWebView.scrollView.delegate = nil;
}
```

and it does not work too.

In addition, I did't refer `weakSelf` in `dealloc` function. It's been annoying me for decades. Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added any Notification observer? like 'addObserver:key:" ? Please share few more parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks , and I have solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you are able to solve this problem. Kindly post your solution in the Answer section. It would help other SO members if they encountered same issue. Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: @Johnic How did you solve this

Answer (score 1):

For ObjC,

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    if (self.superview == nil) {
        self.scrollView.delegate = nil;
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52046816/443530